# Creating Windows VM in KVM/QEMU using GNOME Boxes from a Backed-Up OS

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, backup, qemu, kvm

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm looking for guidance on how to create a Windows virtual machine using KVM, QEMU, and GNOME Boxes on a Linux system. I have recently migrated my Windows and applications from one hard drive to another using a migration tool. Here's my scenario:

I used a tool to migrate my Windows OS and applications from Drive C to another hard drive.
I've since installed Linux on my system and set up KVM, QEMU, and GNOME Boxes.
I have a backup of the Windows OS that I want to use as the basis for the virtual machine.
I would appreciate help in understanding the step-by-step process to create a virtual machine in GNOME Boxes using the backed-up Windows OS. I'm especially interested in ensuring that the migration and virtualization process won't impact the existing data.

How can I create a virtual machine  using a backed-up Windows OS that was migrated from Drive C to another hard drive?

I'm relatively new to virtualization and appreciate any advice or guidance you can provide. If you have experience with similar setups or resources to recommend, I'd be grateful for those as well.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards,

Abdallah Ahmed